# How to pass a set of different kinds of templated components to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have components:

```
struct ComponentStorage : Storage{
    ...
};

template<typename T = ComponentStorage>
class Component{
public:
T* storage;
...
}
```

There are derived classes of the form:

```
struct Component2Storage : Storage{
    ...
};

template<typename T = Component2Storage>
class Component2 : public Component<T>{...}
```

There are multiple levels of inheritance both for Component and for Storage.

My question has to do with functions that with take a Component as input, for example:

```
void myFunction(unordered_set<Component*> components){...} // This won't compile
```

How do I modify my function so I can pass a set containing different kinds of components which may be using different kinds of storage? The actual function doesn't treat different kinds of components differently.

Comment: Make `myFunction` a template. Or make sure your components have a common base class. Different instatiations of `Component<T>` are distinct and unrelated classes.

Comment: @super Can you provide an example please? My Component class is the base class. All components either derive from Component, or from some other class that derives from Component, or from some other class that derives from some other class that.... eventually derives from Component.

Comment: An example of what? The main issue here is that there is no such thing as a `Component*`. `Component` is not a class, it's a class template. `Component<int>` is a class, so `Component<int>*` would make sense. `Component*` is just invalid syntax.

Comment: @super , yes I understand that. But If I put Component<Storage> it won't compile either, and since the set can contain different kinds of Components, for example Derived<DerivedStorage> and Derived2<DerivedStorage2> I'm wondering how to phrase it.

Comment: It can't though. The set can't contain different kinds or Components with your current design.

Comment: @super But if ultimately they're all ComponentBase then there is just one kind really...

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear from your question if that's a valid option for you. Why do you need the templates to begin with? At a glance it just seems easier to make `Component` a non-template class and having a `StorageBase* storage;` in it.

Comment: @super Well, the short answer is so that each component can add its own kind of variables to storage, just by using a different storage which inherits from storage, but the same member variable is used. Using CRTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store different components in the same container, you need polymorphism.

So you need your `Component`s to have a common base class, to be able to treat them as such.

```
struct ComponentStorage : Storage{
    ...
};

class ComponentBase {
    // ... define your common interface
}

template<typename T = ComponentStorage>
class Component : public ComponentBase{
public:
T* storage;
...
}
```

Now you could treat all components as `ComponentBase*` and handle them through the common interface defined.

Storing a `std::variant<...all the component types>` or `std::any` in the set could also be an option, but it comes with it's own set of pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for the last bit about std::variant and std::any. It is good to know about alternatives.